# What is "CacheGroup" for in webpack

Tags: caching, webpack

It's very hard for me to understand why it is called `cacheGroup`. What is that being cached? What will be grouped? Modules? How does **webpack** group modules according to the rules the `cacheGroup` sets.

Answer (score 7):

Well, after 3 days' reading posts/docs on the internet, I seem to understand that design intention for **webpack**.

A doc by [sokra](https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693) on GITHUB says:

> The optimization assigns modules to cache groups

So it *IS* module which would be grouped.

The new chunk(s) generated by a `cacheGroup`'s rules would be related to the all the original chunk(s) by `ChunkGroup` according to the post by [Tobias Koppers](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366) on medium. Here `original` means the chunk the new chunk *should* be placed before splitting.

There exists a graph of chunks, by which **webpack** would emit assets.